# Mongodb difference between MongoCollection vs MongoCollectionBase

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository

I try to upgrade my mongo c# driver.With 2.2.3 driver.  MongoCollectionBase comes and support to async methods.If I change my collection to MongoCollection to MongoCollectionBase that time I lose some abilities like removeall,FindAllAs etc,also many of my method implementation change.

Actually shoud I go on to use MongoCollection or switch to MongoCollectionBase.

Is there any suggested repository sample for mongodb c# driver 2.2.3

Comment: typically, Classes with suffix "Base" are just abstract base classes which define common members for further sub classes

Comment: ..so it is not unusual that those classes have limited functionality. take note, that they are `abstract` and tehrefore always hold a reference to some of their subclasses (like `MongoCollection`) under the hood

Comment: @nozzleman for example In MongoCollection class have Insert function but MongoCollectionBase InsertOne function.Should I Implement both or select one

Comment: i am not familiar w/ MongoDB, i just wanted to point out what Base means, whe in doubt, I would say pick what suits your needs

Comment: @nozzleman: that is try about typical usages of "base" in names, but removing functionality from an existing class is usually not done without providing a replacement. I think that's what the post owner was looking for